# Keep one subview in the same place on the screen while a new viewcontroller is pushed to the navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a "home screen" with a number of image buttons. Upon tapping one of the buttons, a detail view controller is pushed onto the navcontroller. However, visually, I want the image from the button to stay in the same place on the screen while the new viewcontroller transitions into place behind it.

An example of this with modal controllers is adding a photo to an email or message. The photo you select in the gallery grows in size (as if it's moving towards you) while the compose message view slides into place in the background, and then the the photo shrinks into place on the message view.

A few options I thought of:

- Upon tapping the button, have the image be placed into the same spot on the screen as a subview of the UIWindow. Do the animation / transition and then make the image be a subview of the new viewcontroller's view.
- Same as above, but with a modal view controller with a clear background
- Have the UINavigationController be a subview and do the above with the parent view of UINavigationController

All of the options above are similar, but I was curious as to whether there's a better way to do this, and where the code would live. Should I subclass UINavigationController and put the transition code there? Or maybe AppDelegate (that seems wrong, though)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with adding a subview to either the navigation controller or window, but there is some view hierarchy gymnastics that is required.

You will need to provide a means for both the `master` and `detail` view controllers to have a reference to the `imageView` an ivar on each should be fine.

```
// PSMasterViewController.m
@interface PSMasterViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation PSMasterViewController

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

// ...
@end
```

I've put this in the implementation as I don't care to make it public for the master view controller but your needs may differ.

Same again for the `detailViewController`

```
// PSDetailViewController.h
@interface PSMasterViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

// PSDetailViewController.m
@implementation PSDetailViewController

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

// ...
@end
```

Now assuming that the imageView is created and presented already in the master view controller we need to implement some view gymnastics when we are about to push

```
- (void)methodThatPushesTheNextViewController;
{
    CGRect destinationFrame = [self.view convertRect:self.imageView.frame toView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.imageView.frame = destinationFrame;

    PSDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[PSDetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.imageView = self.imageView;
    self.imageView = nil; // The detailViewController should own this now
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now in the detail view controller we need to do the opposite of what we have just done, `viewDidAppear:` is a good place especially as you mentioned you might want to move and scale

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect startFrame = [self.view convertRect:self.imageView.frame fromView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.imageView.frame = startFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                     animations:^{
                         self.imageView.frame = [self someNewFrame];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: I made some minor changes, but this is working very nicely...thanks!

Comment: I was looking to do this exact thing. @Paul.s technique doesnt work on iOS7+ anymore. So for folks on 7+, we need to use custom transitions. on animateTransition method, we usually add toViewController.view as subview to containerView, after that also add imageView as subview to containerView.

Answer (score 0):

**option 1**

You can do that without a ModalViewController as well. First thing to keep in mind, you will have to remove the image and again to your pushedViewController, because if the view transition takes place, a new viewController is added again and your previous view is gone.
  So do this by sending a NSNotification to the viewController that is getting pushed and create the view with the same frame. Also remember to remove the view from superview before you push the new ViewController.

**Option2**

If all your viewcontrollers that need to have the concerned view, are inherited from a single ViewController subclass, you can call [super init] method to create the view and add it in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the "UIView Animation " on the view as conceived by you or you can use iCarousel to have sharper Animation [icarousel SourceCode](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)